# How do I pass the HttpServletRequest object to the test case?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

Now I am writing the test case of my class. I want to pass the HttpServletRequest object parameter to my test case method to check whether the method is working or not. So any one give me the suggestion to that.

```
public void testCheckBatchExecutionSchedule() throws Exception
    {
        assertTrue("Batch is Completed :", returnPointsRatingDisputeFrom.checkBatchExecutionSchedule(request));
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`HttpServletRequest` is an interface.  In the past, I've simply created a class (such as `TestHttpServletRequest`) that had an empty method body for every method in `HttpServletRequest`, except for the ones I actually needed.  For most of the methods, I returned an instance variable and included a setter for that instance variable so that the test case can define what to return.  `HttpServletRequest` has a lot of methods, but most IDEs (I use Eclipse) can generate the method stubs.

The problem with `HttpServletRequestWrapper` is that it still requires another `HttpServletRequest` to be passed into its constructor to serve as the default behavior for each method.  Passing `null` results in a `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 77):

Spring provides a class called [MockHttpServletRequest](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mock/web/MockHttpServletRequest.html), which can be used to test code that needs a HttpServletRequest.

```
public void testCheckBatchExecutionSchedule() throws Exception
{
   MockHttpServletRequest request = new MockHttpServletRequest();
   request.addParameter("parameterName", "someValue");
   assertTrue("Batch is Completed :", returnPointsRatingDisputeFrom.checkBatchExecutionSchedule(request));
}
```

Comment: I've found other mocks of this class online and this is the only one that includes logic that works similar to the original class.  For example, `getRequestURL()` actually assembles a URL from the other attributes, not just regurgitates what's been specified with `setRequestURL()` or a constructor.

Answer (score 24):

you should mock out the request object using a mocking library, like http://code.google.com/p/mockito/

```
public void testCheckBatchExecutionSchedule() throws Exception
{
   HttpServletRequest mockRequest = mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
   //setup the behaviour here (or do it in setup method or something)
   when(mockRequest.getParameter("parameterName")).thenReturn("someValue");
   assertTrue("Batch is Completed :", returnPointsRatingDisputeFrom.checkBatchExecutionSchedule(mockRequest));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated Feb 2018: [OpenBrace Limited has closed down](https://closingbraces.net/openbrace/), and its ObMimic product is no longer supported.

You can also use the [ObMimic](http://www.openbrace.com) library of Servlet API test-doubles:

```
import com.openbrace.obmimic.mimic.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestMimic;

public void testCheckBatchExecutionSchedule() throws Exception
{
   HttpServletRequestMimic request = new HttpServletRequestMimic();
   // Configure the request as necessary...
   // e.g. request.getMimicState().getRequestParameters().set("name", "value");
   assertTrue("Batch is Completed :", returnPointsRatingDisputeFrom.checkBatchExecutionSchedule(request));
}
```

To configure the request, the HttpServletRequestMimic has a getMimicState() method that returns an HttpServletRequestState through which all relevant details of the request can be configured (and through which you can access any associated ServletContext, HttpSession etc and similarly configure these if necessary). Documentation for the HttpServletRequestState includes a [summary](http://www.openbrace.com/main/docs/src/docs/pages/MimicStateSummary.html#HttpServletRequestState) of its properties and methods as well as fully detailed [Javadoc](http://www.openbrace.com/main/docs/src/docs/api/com/openbrace/obmimic/state/servlet/http/HttpServletRequestState.html).

Note that:

- ObMimic also provides similar "mimic" classes for HttpServletResponse, ServletContext, HttpSession, ServletConfig etc.
- A free "Community Edition" of ObMimic is available from the website's [download](http://www.openbrace.com/main/pages/download/download-current.html) page.
- The only library you need to add to your project for this is ObMimic's /lib/obmimic.jar (assuming the Servlet API itself is already present).
- The [ObMimic](http://www.openbrace.com) website provides full documentation, including a [Getting Started](http://www.openbrace.com/main/docs/src/docs/pages/GettingStartedShort.html) guide, a set of [How To](http://www.openbrace.com/main/docs/src/docs/pages/howto/index.html) guides with example code, detailed [Javadoc](http://www.openbrace.com/main/docs/src/docs/api/index.html) etc.

Answer (score -3):

By using API given by tomcat you can get HttpServletRequest object

```
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.getLastServicedRequest();
```

This will get the last request passed to a servlet for servicing from the current thread.

This work in the Tomcats "Strict Servlet Compliance" mode only. To enable it Add following JVM parameter:

```
org.apache.catalina.STRICT_SERVLET_COMPLIANCE=true
```